# Selenium tbody text extraction

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The web application I am trying to automate has a diagnostic tool that allows to ping to a website. It provides output in a box that has a table structure (all of it is included i na ).

I am automating it using Selenium WebDriver and Java to program one. It is structured as a JUnit 4 test and uses WebDriver (not Selenium RC, but the newer one)

Here is what it looks like:

```
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;">PING ds-any-fp3-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109) 56(84) bytes of data.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;">64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=81.9 ms</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;">64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=2 ttl=53 time=148 ms</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;">64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=4 ttl=53 time=143 ms</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;">--- ds-any-fp3-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com ping statistics ---</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;">5 packets transmitted, 3 received, 40% packet loss, time 4012ms</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;">rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 81.917/124.763/148.373/30.349 ms</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And here is what it looks like on the page:

```
PING ds-any-fp3-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=81.9 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=2 ttl=53 time=148 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=4 ttl=53 time=143 ms
--- ds-any-fp3-real.wa1.b.yahoo.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 3 received, 40% packet loss, time 4012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 81.917/124.763/148.373/30.349 ms
```

I need to parse this text using Selenium WebDriver and pass the JUnit test if the ping was successful (doesn't matter if the packets have been lost), I need to extract an IP address as well.

Is there any way I can extract the particular part of the page source (maybe, using driver.getPageSource() in some sophisticated way or finding this piece by xpath and then calling getText()?) and then parse it to get IP out? The way I tried it is as folows:

```
String IP = "";
String textToParse = //Here, we should have a way to get the string that would contain IP.
String tokenSeparators = "()"; // since our IP is enclosed by brackets 
String tokens[] = textToParse.split(tokenSeparators);
for(int i = 0; i<tokens.length; i++){
    if(tokens[i].matches("^[1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9]?\\.[1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9]?\\.[1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9]?\\.[1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9]?$")){ // IP regexp
         IP = tokens[i]
    }

}
```

Let me know how to extract the text that I need to parse and whether there are errors in my code (for example, if my regexp is right)

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> allTds=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[style*='font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;']");
String allTdText[]=new String[allTds.size()];
int i=0;
for(WebElement eachTd:allTds)
 {
    allTdText[i++]=eachTd.getText();
 }
```

By using above logic you will get all td tags data in String array. after that parse each individual arraye element as your requirement.

**Example** :

String a="64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=81.9 ms";

For getting IP address alone

System.out.println(a.substring(a.indexOf("(")+1,a.indexOf(")")));

it will return **98.138.253.109**

Comment: This is indeed a great way to solve the problem, will give it a try.